# Firestore HTTP Insomnia query : Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, insomnia

I'm trying to query my Firestore database using an HTTP query via the Insomnia API:

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/typebot/databases/(default)/documents/users`

with this body:

```
{
  "structuredQuery": {
    "from": [
        {
            "collectionId": "users"
        }
    ],
    "where": {
        "fieldFilter": {
            "field": {
                "fieldPath": "email"
            },
            "op": "EQUAL",
            "value": {
                "stringValue": "email@test.com"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And I get the following error:

> HTTP query: Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: So it's just this query, and no others having this problem?

Comment: I forgot to give what endpoint I was querying. I edited the question. If I'm querying for example  `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/typebot/databases/(default)/documents/users/<DOC_ID>` => it works

Comment: every Structured query are failing

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you're using to make the request.  The error sounds like a problem with the HTTP client, not Firestore.  We should be able to reproduce the issue using what you provide here.

Comment: I'm using Insomnia

Comment: I also agreed this might be an issue caused by Insomnia could you try calling the same endpoint with a [Firestore client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) test code?

Answer (score 2):

May try to change "GET" to "POST"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem performing a `GET` request:

```
GET https://us-central1-my-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/getUsers HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json
{
        "minAge": "18"
}
```

against an endpoint defined by this Firestore HTTP Cloud Function:

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // find matching users by age limit.
    const ageLimit = req.body.age;
    ... 
  
});
```

Turns out, based on [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body), that a request body with `GET` does not have any meaning in the sense that the HTTP spec recommends that the "message-body SHOULD be ignored when handling the request" (presumably, by the server, and that the Firestore server implements this behavior). Oddly, I didn't catch this issue running the exact same function locally with the Functions emulator, so it is likely the local server ignores this recommendation.

To fix the issue, I changed my function to parse the query params instead of a request body:

```
exports.getUsers = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    // find matching users by age limit.
    const ageLimit = req.query.age; // extract the age as a query param
    ... 
  
});
```

and the request:

```
GET https://us-central1-my-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/getUsers?age=18
```